# Plot data from the serial port

Tags: .net, serial-port, arduino

I got a serial port in .NET at 9600 baudrate. The incoming data is
numeric, it's the time between 2 pulses of a motor encoder, it's the [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_per_minute) of the motor actualy.

How do I plot the data in real time?

Comment: Plot using what display technology? are you looking for WPF charting controls, WinForms ones or are you seeking guidance for rolling your own?  Please be more specific so the community knows how to answer your question.

Comment: Here's some help: the incoming data is not numeric.  They are bytes.  Maybe bytes that represent ASCII digits, hard to tell.

Comment: I want to implement zedgraph, to chart the change of rpm. Data is send by the arduino in the form of one integer reprezenting time it took for one revolution 2056 microseconds for max pwm

Answer (score 1):

A simple plotter is fairly easy to do. You can spend hours looking for a just right library or program or just write your own in equivalent time.

Here is how I have done it in the past

- Allocate a circular buffer - about 2-4K data points should be sufficient
- take your serial data store it in the serial buffer
- get a drawable area
- map the height of the drawable area to the maximum - minimum value you wish to display
- map the width of the drawable area to the number of points you wish to display
- start a thread which takes in the serial data, parses it and puts it in the circular buffer,
- start another thread which checks for new data in buffer periodically, plots the data in the circular buffer on a back buffer and then updates the drawable area displayed with the backbuffer.

I had a similar issue some time back. I looked for a simple, light program that would do it do out of the box. I finally gave in and coded my own program using Win32 calls. A .NET implementation would be simpler.

http://www.fast-product-development.com/real-time-serial-data-plot.html